# How can I inject data get in router.beforeEach in my vuejs component?

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js, vue-router

I use router.beforeEach to protect some view. I fetch my user before entering in my vue. I want to use this user in all my authenticated pages. How can I inject data get in router.beforeEach in my vuejs component?

Here my routes definition:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import AuthService from './services/AuthService';

import Index from './pages/Index.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
    {path: '/', name: 'index', component: Index, meta: {requiresAuth: true}},
    ...
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        AuthService().getUser(user => {
            if (user) {
                next(vm => {
                    vm.user = user
                });
            } else {
                ...
            }
        });
    }
    ...
});

export default router;
```

here my Index.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{user}}
    </div>
</template>
<script type="text/ecmascript-6">
    export default {
        data(){
            console.log(this.user);
            console.log(this.$route.user);
            return {}
        },
        mounted(){
            console.log(this.user);
            console.log(this.$route.user);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Everything is undefined

I don't want to make a `beforeRouteEnter` in my component because it will make a second API call.

Comment: Are you using Vuex store?

Comment: @TusharArora If there is no solution with in vue-router I will use vuex. I try to avoid vuex for now.

Comment: You code is working fine for me

Answer (score 3):

I normally separate the files and then import the js file to my page, here is how I implement **beforeEach** rule:

1. Routes file:

   ```
   import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

   let routes = [
     {
       path: '/',
       component: require('./views/Home')
     },
     {
       path: '/about',
       component: require('./views/About'),
     }
   ];

   export default new VueRouter({
       routes,
   });
   ```
2. Vue App file:

   ```
   import router from './routes';

   // Here goes my logic
   router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
       if ( from.name == 'About' ) {
           next(false);
       } else {
           next();
       }
   });

   const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',

       router
   });
   ```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I see 3 issues:

1. The vue-router documentation shows you can access the vm in `next` in a component's `beforeRouteEnter`, not a global `beforeEach`.
2. In `next`, the vm has already been created because you can access its properties, so you wouldn't be able to see `this.user` in the `data` function. Maybe in the `mounted` function, but we don't know if the vm is returned before or after the component is mounted.
3. You shouldn't set top-level properties on a vm because they will not be reactive: see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set .

Perhaps your `AuthService` could store the user and your components get the user from there?